# When is this polynomial sequence smaller than $2^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For every $k$, define the sequence:

$$ S_k(n) := 1+2^k +\ldots + n^k + (n+1)^k $$

When $n$ is sufficiently large, $S_k(n)$ must be smaller than $2^n$, since $S_k(n)$ grows polynomially with $n$ while $2^n$ grows exponentially.

My question is: when exactly does it becomes smaller? I.e, what is the smallest $n$ (as a function of $k$) such that:

$$ S_k(n) < 2^n $$
?

I managed to calculate some simple cases manually:

- When $k=0$, $S_0(n)=n+1$, so the smallest $n$ is $2$.
- When $k=1$, $S_1(n)=(n+1)(n+2)/2$, so the smallest $n$ is $4$.

But then it becomes more complicated. Is there a more general solution?

Comment: Sounds like [Bernoulli Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Sum_of_powers) might provide some more insight here...

Comment: Asymptotically $S_k(n) \sim \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$ so solving $ \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} = 2^n$ should give you a fairly good approximation (atleast for large $k$). For example for $k=5$ the true solution is $n \geq 26.15$ while the approximation gives $n\geq 25.42$. For $n=10$ the true solution is $n\geq 62.55$ while the approximation gives $n\geq 62.05$.

Comment: (Ref comment above: for integer $k$ the sum evaluates to a polynomial so I do root-finding on this numerically. It's just to get a sense of how good the approximation is even though only integer values are "good" values here.)